# how to prevent entering mismatched values in jquery autocomplete search

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, autocomplete

i have developed jquery autocomplete search. and i want to change it to when a user type a word  and if there no results for that keyword i want to validate it with popup showing invalid input. Please advice

Ex: if user type "testing" and if there not any autocomplete result for that use should see a message before entering search button

mycode

```
 jQuery(function(){
    jQuery("#searchg").autocomplete({
        source:'government.php',
        delay: 300 ,

        minLength:1,
        select: function(event, ui) {

            if (ui.item.desc!="")
            {


                jQuery('#search1').

val(ui.item.desc);
        }
        else if ((ui.item.desc =="") &&(ui.item.icon !="") ) {
            jQuery('#categories_id1').val(ui.item.icon);

        }

    }
```

});

Comment: From a user experience viewpoint, you should never interrupt the user while they are typing. Unless by "popup" you mean "tooltip", which may be acceptable.

Comment: @Joe : i want to prevent user entering mismatch values and press Search button , which means if a user type mismatch word and pres search button, i want to validate it and give tooltip message .not to interrupt him while typing. please advice